# Make tags [pfuser], [pfquery] a synonym of [parse-ios-sdk]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Make tags [pfuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pfuser), [pfquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pfquery) synonyms of [parse-ios-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-ios-sdk) for the following reasons:

- `PFUser` and `PFQuery` are classes of the Parse iOS SDK.
- Keeping separate tags on a granular class name level unnecessarily fragments questions which negatively impacts tag performance. In an extreme case, there are dozens more classes in the Parse iOS SDK, each of which could have their own tag.

This tag request is part of the Parse Community's effort to maintain Parse Platform related tags on Stack Exchange, as described [here](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/parse-related-stackexchange-tags/739).

Comment: There are [quite some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pfuser+-ios+-objective-c+-swift) [with these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pfquery+-ios+-objective-c+-swift) that don't appear to have anything to do with the ios sdk. These would need manual cleanup before the tags can be synonymised I presume

Comment: @Bergi Well spotted, is manual cleanup the only option, or is it possible to just remove the tag from all questions, which contain another parse related tag anyway?